# Vertica: Over Clause issue

Tags: sql, window-functions, vertica

I have below table having pk & sales Column.

Trying to calculate 3rd column(sales/(sum of Sales))
i.e 100/1000,50/1000 etc....

```
pk | sales
----+-------
  1 |   100
  2 |    50
  3 |   250
  4 |   100
  5 |   500
```

Is same is possible in vertica..

I tried cumulative sum  using below query.

```
select pk,sales,
sum(sales) over (order by pk) cumulative_sum
from sum_test
order by pk;
```

Please suggest..

Comment: `sales / sum(sales) over()` ?

Comment: Does the analytic function available for you?

Comment: "I tried cumulative sum using below query." And? What happened?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Vertica. In standard SQL the expression `sum(sales) over (order by pk)` gives you a running total for the given order. To get the total sum over all rows instead, you'd remove the order by clause: `sum(sales) over ()`.

```
select 
  pk,
  sales,
  sum(sales) over () as total,
  sales / sum(sales) over () as percentage
from sum_test
order by pk;
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting an ORDER BY in your window clause will lead to default framing of ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.

Leaving the window clause blank will get you the sum over all rows that you desire:

```
with s as (
  select 1 as pk, 100 as sales
  union all select 2, 50
  union all select 3, 250
  union all select 4, 100
  union all select 5, 500
)
select *, sum(sales) over ()
from s
;

 pk | sales | ?column? 
----+-------+----------
  1 |   100 |     1000
  2 |    50 |     1000
  3 |   250 |     1000
  4 |   100 |     1000
  5 |   500 |     1000
```